# How to automatically activate users after registration without activation email?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, hooks, user-registration

I want to auto-login my users after signup without an activation email requirement (I'm not concerned about spammers). How might I go about doing this? Thanks!

Comment: Then you need to ask them for a password in the registration form

Comment: @One Trick Pony, do you happen to know of any good plugins that can accomplish modifying the registration for and disabling the email activation requirement?

Comment: Try [WP User Registration](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-password-register)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another plugin for you, allows the user to register in the sidebar and stay on the same page - [Ninety Ajax Login/Register for WordPress](http://codecanyon.net/item/ninety-ajax-loginregister-for-wordpress/158711)